# Проблема с Jquery :eq

Tags: jquery

Есть список

```html
<ul class=".lk_panel_ul">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

в подвале в документ рэди делаю переключение

```
$(".lk_panel_ul li:eq(0)").hide();
$(".lk_panel_ul li:eq(1)").hide();
```

Так вот первый li скрывается, все верное
а второй нет, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: В теге `<ul class=".lk_panel_ul">` удалите точку возле класса

Comment: Опишите свою задачу. Может Вам `css` тут лучше подойдет?

Comment: Точку тут когда писал поставил, ошибся

Answer (score 0):

1. Классы в тегах именуются без точки, то есть:

   ```
   <ul class="lk_panel_ul"> ..
   ```
2. Попробуйте `:eq` в "функциональном" формате так сказать:

   ```
   var $child = $('.lk_panel_ul').find('li');

   $child.eq(0).hide();
   $child.eq(1).hide(); ...
   ```